# jQuery toggle() the other way around?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a simpel toggle() function to show and hide a div when a button is clicked.
Now when the button is clicked the animation slides upwards. I was wondering if it is possible to make it slide downwards when the button is clicked. 
See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1y9pgmu/), or the code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        $( ".submit" ).click(function() {
          $( ".show_to_hide, .hide_to_show" ).toggle( "slow" );
        });
        </script>
        <style>
        .hide_to_show{display:none;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="show_to_hide">

          This is hidden on click


          </div>

          <div class="hide_to_show">

          This is shown on click

          </div>

          <button class="submit">
          Submit
          </button>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do  Don't link to a fiddle.  Make an onsite snippet instead.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you mean on first button click make the animation slide downwards. You can achieve this simply by moving `hide_to_show` class div above the `show_to_hide` div like:

```js
$(".submit").click(function() {
  $( ".show_to_hide, .hide_to_show" ).toggle( "slow" );
});
```

```css
.hide_to_show{display:none;}.hide_to_show,.show_to_hide{height:40px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="hide_to_show">
    This is shown on click
  </div>
  <div class="show_to_hide">
    This is hidden on click
  </div>

  <button class="submit" type="button">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! But what if I am not able to move the divs around? Any workaround?