# Hide Div with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wanted to have the first DIV hidden if the 2nd DIV is shown in the frontend and vice versa when the pageloads.

If 1st DIV = block
2nd DIV should be = none

and

if 2nd DIV = block
1st DIV should be = none

Thanks peeps!

Comment: Show what you’ve tried and tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. You can get better answers when you provide research.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery toggle() the other way around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60725884/jquery-toggle-the-other-way-around)

Answer (score 0):

You must create 2 clases:

```css
.show{
  display:block;
}
.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

then with js add or remove clases, for example:

```js
const toogleElements = () =>{
  const div1 = document.getElementById("div1")
  const div2 = document.getElementById("div2")
  if(div1.classList.contains("show") && div2.classList.contains("hide")){
    div1.classList.remove("show");
    div2.classList.remove("hide");
    div1.classList.add("hide");
    div2.classList.add("show");
  }
  if(div1.classList.contains("hide") && div2.classList.contains("show")){
    div1.classList.remove("hide");
    div2.classList.remove("show");
    div1.classList.add("show");
    div2.classList.add("hide");
  }
}
```

But you can use a variable to manage the state instead check if has the clases